# T-SQL statement for getting minute from time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using pyodbc for my SQL Server connection. I am trying to retrieve all the data rows (items) that belongs to the minute now (ie. real time). However I am getting an error for the `minute(Time)` and `now()`. I think i might have used the syntax for MySQL instead of SQL Server. I am not sure what is the syntax version for SQL Server.

I'll appreciate if anyone can help. Thank you!

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=RON\SQLEXPRESS;'
                      'Database=sys;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT item from sys.table1 where minute(Time) = minute(now())")')

for i in cursor:
    print(i)

#example of Data
#Time                   #Item
#2023-06-30 00:00:00    #Apple
#2023-06-30 00:01:00    #Orange
#2023-06-30 00:01:00    #Banana

#eg now is 2023-06-30 00:01:00, the output would be Orange & Banana
```

Comment: Please show the full error message you are getting

Answer (score 1):

The syntax in Microsoft SQL Server is `DATEPART` and you specify an interval, so in your case

```
SELECT DATEPART(minute, GETDATE()) as CurrentMinute
```

However, that doesn't sound like what you want. If you're trying to get the records that are less than a minute old, use `DATEDIFF` to find their age.

For example

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE DATEDIFF(second, [Time], GETDATE()) < 60
```

EDIT: BTW, the reason why is if you compare the minute of the record to the minute of the current time, you will get all occurrences where just the minute part matches regardless of what other parts don't match. So if you ran the query at 10:29, you'd get entries from 8:29 AM this morning, 10:29 PM yesterday, etc.

Comment: Hi Robert, actually this is part of my script which further processes the list retrieved from the database. basically i will run it in While loop, and once it hits a new minute, it will trawl the table for all Item that also has the same time(ie. minute). i would need the hour and date to match as well (ie. now time 13-7-23 23:01:00 compare with database 13-7-23 23:01:00 ,01, 02, 03, etc)

Comment: Rather than using `DATEDIFF` it's better to use `WHERE Time > DATEADD(minute, -1, GETDATE()) AND Time < GETDATE()` that way it can use indexes